# Very slow upload of form data in IE11 - Jquery/ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-11

Looked at a million posts on this but cannot find an actual solution.  I am looking for either a solution or confirmation that this is an IE11 bug that I have to deal with.  Trying to use ajax form data to post an image.  Works perfectly in every browser other than IE11 (dont care about other versions of IE).  No matter what i try the post just sits in a pending state as shown here:

[image: pending state network tab]

Sometimes it will finish but will take 100+ seconds to complete, which is not ideal at all.

[image: long running upload]

Anyone have any idea how to work around this with a plugin or another method of uploading images?

my code:

```
    var inputField = $(e.target);
    var rxContainer = $(e.target).closest('.image-preview-container');
    var uploadBtn = $(rxContainer).find('.fileinput-button');
    var uploadBtnTxt = $(uploadBtn).find('span');
    var base64Text = $(rxContainer).find('.base64Text');
    var imageAccessKey = $(rxContainer).find('.AccessKey-div').find('input');
    var image = $(inputField).data('image');
    var blobFile = inputField[0].files[0];
    var fd = new FormData();

fd.append('file', blobFile);
fd.append('nothing', 'nothing');

//disable buttons during upload
$(inputField).prop('disabled', true);
$(uploadBtn).css('opacity', '0.3');
$(':submit').prop('disabled', true);
$(':submit').css('opacity', '0.3');


var xhr;
var uploadImage = function () {     
  showLoadingDialog();
    xhr = $.ajax({
        url: Urls.rximageuploadapi,
        headers: {
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + image
        },
        type: 'POST',
        data: fd ? fd : inputField.serialize(),
        processData: false,
        contentType: false,
        cached: false,
        success: function(response) {
            //load image access key into form
            imageAccessKey.val(response.imageAccessKey);

            //load returned image into preview window
            loadImage(response.image, rxContainer);
            $(base64Text).html(response.image);

            //re-enable buttons after upload
            $(inputField).prop('disabled', false);
            $(uploadBtn).css('opacity', '1');
            $(':submit').prop('disabled', false);
            $(':submit').css('opacity', '1');
            hideLoadingDialog();
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorMessage) {
            //display error message
            clearCanvas(rxContainer);
            uploadBtnTxt.text(Resources.CHOOSEPHOTO_MESSAGE);
            $maxFileSizeError.hide();
            $maxFileTypeError.hide();

            if (jqXHR.status == "500") {
                var errorResponse = jqXHR.responseText;
                var jsonResponse = JSON.parse(errorResponse);
                if (jsonResponse.errors != undefined && jsonResponse.errors.length > 0) {
                    for (var i = 0; i < jsonResponse.errors.length; i++) {
                        var errorText = jsonResponse.errors[i].message;
                        if (errorText == "BLANK_IMAGE" || errorText == "CORRUPTED_FILE") {
                            $corruptedFile.show();
                            break;
                        } else if (errorText == "PASSWORD_PROTECTED") {
                            $passwordProtectedFile.show();
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $fileUploadError.show();
                }
            } else {
                $fileUploadError.show();
            }

            //re-enable buttons after upload
            $(inputField).prop('disabled', false);
            $(uploadBtn).css('opacity', '1');
            $(':submit').prop('disabled', false);
            $(':submit').css('opacity', '1');
            hideLoadingDialog();
        }
    });
}
```

Request payload in IE:
[image]

Request payload in Chrome:
[image]

Comment: jquery version?

Comment: I am using version 2.1.1

Comment: Can you compare the two request bodies? Also pretty crazy that it just takes 'longer' ...

Comment: do you mean compare the two request bodies from browser to browser?

Comment: @CodyG. I uploaded the request payload for IE 11 and Chrome.  The image type doesnt seem to matter if you question that.  It behaves the same for png and jpeg in both browsers as in correct in Chrome and slow in IE

Comment: try giving the Blob a file name argument to FormData, maybe IE11 cares it's missing...

Comment: @dandavis how do you do that?  The receiving api needs the parameter to be "file" for the file upload to work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append

Comment: `formData.append(name, value, filename);`

Comment: But the filename is provided in both payloads so *shrugs*

Comment: tried this, same issue. thanks for the suggestion

Comment: It seems after my research that the issue may have to do with the authorization header.  Removing it responds immediately, but with a 401.  Removed that requirement from my backend app and it worked just fine.  Problem is i need to keep that authorization in.

Comment: So how do you resolve this issue ?